# Prove that MD=(d1+d2+d3)/3 if M is the centroid of the triangle ABC, and d1, d2, d3 and MD are perpendicular to the line under the triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

Here's a picture because I can't really explain the problem. Tried to prove it with using the fact that the centroid divides a median in a ratio $2:1$ and similar triangles but I got stuck.

Comment: Hint: Let $P$ be the midpoint of $CB$. Drop a perpendicular from $P$ to that "line under"

Comment: @Lozenges I tried it but I don't see what I should do next. The only thing I got is that the line M to the side AB is equal to 2/3 P to the side AB and that C to the side AB is 2 times the line P to the side AB. Not sure if that is sufficient

Comment: Ayy Lmao, have you managed to prove that the length of the perpendicular is $(d_2+d_3)/2$?

Comment: @user8734617 No, how would I prove that?

Comment: Median of a trapezoid?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I don't know how I didn't notice that.

Comment: I still don't know what I could use that for

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the x coordinates of points A, B and C respectively. So point A is $ (x_1,d_1)$, point B is $(x_2,d_2)$ and point C is $(x_3,d_3)$. Now M is the centroid of triangle. Therefore y-coordinate of M is $$(\frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{3})$$ hence proved that $$MD=(\frac{d_1+d_2+d_3}{3})$$

Comment: I considered the bottom most horizontal line to be x-axis.

Comment: Yes, but can you prove it without coordinate geometry, I know that there is a formula for the centroid of a triangle, but I would really like to know how to prove it using "normal" euclidean geometry.

Comment: OK sorry I'll just try coz I don't have much idea of Euclidean Geometry

Comment: No problem, it's not your fault since I didn't write it in my question